# заміна букви "і" на "ї"

Tags: чергування

чому дехто інколи замінює літеру "і" на "ї", як от, наприклад "д**ї**я, їхн**ї**, ід**ї**ть, тепер**ї**шн**ї**й, ц**ї**кавити" і т.д., замість "д**і**я, їхн**і**, ід**і**ть, тепер**і**шн**і**й, ц**і**кавити"?

це якась регіональна особливість написання?

які правила існують щодо цього феномену?

Answer (score 2):

Сучасна українська абетка і сучасний український правопис сформувалися не відразу. XIX століття і, мабуть, початок XX століття були періодом різноманітних експериментів, зокрема доволі незвичних для нашого сучасного ока (наприклад, [ярижка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8) — фактично написання українських слів російською абеткою — або [драгоманівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8) з *j* замість *й*, *jа/ьа/jе/ье/jу/ьу/jі* замість *я/є/ю/ї*, *шч* замість *щ*).

Деякі з таких історичних правописних систем української мови, зокрема [Желехівка](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%96%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) і [правопис Смаль-Стоцького та Ґартнера](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%96_%D2%90%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) (можливо, й інші; я особисто натрапляв на це в «Ілюстрованій історії України» Грушевського, однак я не знаю, якого саме правопису дотримувався автор), передбачали **написання *ї* у певних місцях на місці етимологічного *ѣ***. ([*Ѣ* (ять)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF%D1%82%D1%8C) — це давня кирилична літера, що, імовірно, початково позначала один звук для різних слов'янських народів (можливо, це був звук [[æ]](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F)), але з часом вимова розійшлася, наприклад в українській на місці праслов'янського *ѣ* стали вимовляти [i], у російській і білоруській — здебільшого [je], у болгарській і польській — часто [ja] (порівняйте: укр. *хліб* — рос. *хлеб* — болг. *хляб*; укр. *білий* — рос. *белый* — пол. *biały*). Але повернімося від *ѣ* до основної теми…) Літера *ї* в цих випадках позначала не те, що вона позначає в сучасній українській мові, — **не сполучення двох звуків [ji], а всього-на-всього звичайний звук [i]**. При цьому й звичайна літера *і* в цих старих правописних системах теж застовувалась (наприклад у Грушевського бачимо: «дал*ї* починає м*і*шати»). Навіщо майже один і той самий звук [i] позначати двома різними літерами (*і* та *ї*)? Здебільшого вважається, що це виражає різний ступінь м'якшення приголосного перед звуком [i] (***ї* м'якшило попередній приголосний сильніше за *і***).

Нині жоден з поширених правописів (ані правопис 2019, ані правопис 2015, ані навіть харківський правопис) не передбачає використання *ї* в такій ролі (для позначення звуку [i], що на місці етимологічного *ѣ* і/або сильно пом'якшує попередній приголосний). Однак ви можете натрапити на це в старих книжках/творах, а також у дописах поодиноких авторів (прихильників старих правописних систем чи експериментаторів). Утім я не можу назвати конкретних правил (і припускаю, що вони не єдині, а дещо різняться між різними системами).

P.S.: Див. також:

- фрагмент 6:48–7:05 відео [«Іван Нечуй-Левицький проти клятих галичан»](https://youtu.be/J9dyu20z4Dg?t=408) з циклу «Квантова філологія» від «Твоя Підпільної Гуманітарки».

Comment: Якщо брати до уваги деякі діалекти, зокрема мій подільский говір, то там є два різних "і": пом'якшувальне (у більшості випадків; напр. тісто, ніжний) і непомʼякшувальне (на місці переходу о, ы -> і; напр. тільки, ніж). У другому випадку "і" взагалі не пом'якшує попередню приголосну.

Comment: @xpoback, дякую!